# My Irish bank account was just opened last week. Apply for standard visitor uk visa

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, chinese-citizens

Hi I’m from China and I’m an exchange student in Ireland for this semester. 
I intend to visit UK after exams and go back home from the UK. I’d like to say in UK for five days.

MY PROBLEM: I just opened an Irish bank account and put my cash into the account. And I want to use that bank statement as my financial proof. But the thing is that I only opened it last week and put money in last week. And I want to submit the materials at the end of this month (because I want to get the visa as soon as possible so that I can book my flight home).

I don’t have enough months for showing my monthly expenses . Would it be possible for me to get a visa successfully ( due to the short period of stay and enough money to cover my expenses in the UK).

Comment: Where was your money before you put it in the Irish account? Did you have a Chinese bank account? You can show statements from the Chinese account up to the final withdrawal, and then from the Irish account from the initial deposit.

Answer (score 10):

It's unlikely that a week old bank account will be sufficient evidence to successfully get a UK visa. They require a longer financial history.

There is no limit on how many accounts you can submit statements for.  You should also submit statements for whatever bank account your money was in before you transferred it to the new one.  That will give a much better picture of your finances.